# How do I make the javascript and stylesheets reflect immediately in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stylesheet

This is my environment:

```
ruby on rails 4.2.0
unicorn
nginx
```

when I change my javascript or stylesheet, these changes do not reflect immediately, but I have seen with `rails server`, it is ok.

By the way, I have tried to delete all history with `ctrl + shift + delete`.

Comment: http://www.livejs.com/

Comment: Do you use the asset pipeline? Are you in `development` or `production` environment?

Comment: I am in production enviroment, and I do `rails assets:precompile` before I test, and the amazing thing is the css and javascript file is updated, but they have no effects